# What is instance.constructor.constructor and how does it work?

Tags: javascript, constructor

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}   

let person1 = new Person("Eve");

person1.constructor; // Output: ƒ Person(name) {}

person1.constructor.constructor; // Output: ƒ Function() { [native code] }

person1.constructor.constructor("console.log(1)"); // Output: ƒ anonymous() {console.log(1)}

person1.constructor.constructor("console.log(1)")(); // Output: 1
```

Can someone help me to understand `person1.constructor.constructor`, `person1.constructor.constructor("console.log(1)")` and `person1.constructor.constructor("console.log(1)")()`? I do not understand the outputs.

Answer (score 1):

The `.constructor` property of an instance points to the function associated with the internal prototype. As you can see, `person1.constructor` gives you `Person`, because `person1` was created with `new Person` (`person1`'s internal prototype is `Person.prototype`)

What is the `Person`? It's a function. The `.constructor` of a function will be the function associated with the internal prototype of that function - that is, the constructor associated with `Function.prototype`, which is `Function`, the function constructor:

```js
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}   

let person1 = new Person("Eve");

console.log(person1.constructor.constructor === Function);
```

You can pass strings to `new Function` to create functions out of them.

```
person1.constructor.constructor("console.log(1)");
```

is just like

```
Function("console.log(1)");
```

which returns a function that, when called, logs 1.

```js
const fn = Function("console.log(1)");
console.log(fn);
fn();
```

Comment: supposed I have `let x = new Function("123");`, then `x` will be `f anonymous() { 123 }`. May I know why there is no key for 123? As I understand, an object contains key-value pairs.

Comment: That's not an object, that's just an unused expression inside a block. Like `function foo() { 123; }` Possible, just meaningless.